# iTextSharp Form Field Not Displaying ampersands, &, with SetField

Tags: pdf, encoding, itext

I'm having an issue with iTextSharp and a PDF form (form fields specifically) that I've spend nearly two days on that I am direly hoping someone has the answer to.

I have a PDF form that when I open it as a user I can enter ampersands, &, into form fields just fine.  However, when I use iTextSharp to fill in a form field value using .SetField the ampersands disappear.  I have tried using & (which actually causes all the text in the field to appear as blank), the unicode representation of &, not flattening the form, flattening the form, etc. all to no avail.  I am not sure what the issue could be as I mentioned the form field can certainly accept commas and ampersands with it's default encoding.

Is there something i'm missing?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Using iText 4.1.2.0
    GeneratePDF2()
End Sub

Private Sub GeneratePDF2()
    ''//The directory to output files to
    Dim WorkingFolder = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop

    Dim FormFileName = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "testfile.pdf")
    Dim FinalFileName = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "Final.pdf")

    ''//The name of the form field that we are going to create
    Dim TextFieldName = "form1[0].#subform[0].Table3[0].Row2[0].Line2_FullName_and_AddressofEmployer[0]"

    Dim FieldValue As String = "Jonathan & Chris & Mark" ' Does Not Work
    'Dim FieldValue As String = "Jonathan and Chris and Mark" ' Works

    Dim Letter As RandomAccessFileOrArray
    'Create a PDF reader object based on the PDF template
    Dim PDFReader As PdfReader
    'Dim BAOS1 As MemoryStream
    Dim Stamper As PdfStamper


    Dim BAOS As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim Copy As PdfCopyFields = New PdfCopyFields(BAOS)

    Dim FormFilePath As String = FormFileName
    Letter = New RandomAccessFileOrArray(FormFilePath)
    'Create a PDF reader object based on the PDF template
    PDFReader = New PdfReader(Letter, Nothing)

    Dim BAOS1 As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Stamper = New PdfStamper(PDFReader, BAOS1)

    Dim FormFields As AcroFields = Stamper.AcroFields

    'Set field value
    FormFields.SetField(TextFieldName, FieldValue)

    'Rename field after setting value
    Dim RenamedFormFieldName As String
    RenamedFormFieldName = String.Concat(Guid.NewGuid().ToString, "_", Guid.NewGuid().ToString)

    FormFields.RenameField(TextFieldName, RenamedFormFieldName)

    ' flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
    ' to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
    Stamper.FormFlattening = True
    ' close the pdf
    Stamper.Close()

    'This could be the correct location
    Copy.AddDocument(New PdfReader(BAOS1.ToArray))

    Copy.Writer.CloseStream = False
    Copy.Close()

    PDFReader = New PdfReader(BAOS.ToArray())
    Stamper = New PdfStamper(PDFReader, New FileStream(FinalFileName, FileMode.Create))


    Stamper.FormFlattening = True
    Stamper.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem, I'm using version 5.1.1.0. Below is sample code that creates a PDF, adds a field to it and then sets the field's value to `This & that`. (Its in three steps because I don't know how to add a field during the initial PDF creation.) I also tried manually creating a PDF in Acrobat and I was able to set the field to an ampersand just fine, too. Are you creating the form field in iTextSharp or another program? Can you post that PDF somewhere so we can look at it?

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''//The directory to output files to
        Dim WorkingFolder = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop

        ''//This sample code creates a base PDF, then adds a text field to it and finally sets the field value.
        ''//These filenames represent those three actions
        Dim BaseFileName = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "Base.pdf")
        Dim FormFileName = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "Form.pdf")
        Dim FinalFileName = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "Final.pdf")

        ''//The name of the form field that we are going to create
        Dim TextFieldName = "Text1"

        ''//Create our base PDF
        Using FS As New FileStream(BaseFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
            Using Doc As New Document(PageSize.LETTER)
                Using W = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS)
                    Doc.Open()
                    Doc.NewPage()
                    Doc.Add(New Paragraph("This is my form"))
                    Doc.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        ''//Add our form field
        Using FS As New FileStream(FormFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
            Dim R1 = New PdfReader(BaseFileName)
            Using S As New PdfStamper(R1, FS)
                Dim F As New TextField(S.Writer, New Rectangle(50, 50, 500, 100), TextFieldName)
                S.AddAnnotation(F.GetTextField(), 1)
                S.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        ''//Set the field value to text with an ampersand
        Using FS As New FileStream(FinalFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
            Dim R2 = New PdfReader(FormFileName)
            Using S As New PdfStamper(R2, FS)
                S.AcroFields.SetField(TextFieldName, "This & that")
                S.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT**

I just tried it with the PDF you sent and its working just fine for me. Below is the full code that I ran. [Here's the PDF it made](http://www.vendiadvertising.com/Transfer/Final.pdf). Are you sure you're not doing something else to the PDF (I don't know what.) If you create a brand new Windows Applications and use the below code against 5.1.1.0 does it work for you?

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''//The directory to output files to
        Dim WorkingFolder = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop

        Dim FormFileName = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "testfile.pdf")
        Dim FinalFileName = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "Final.pdf")

        ''//The name of the form field that we are going to create
        Dim TextFieldName = "form1[0].#subform[0].Table3[0].Row2[0].Line2_FullName_and_AddressofEmployer[0]"

        ''//Set the field value to text with an ampersand
        Using FS As New FileStream(FinalFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
            Dim R2 = New PdfReader(FormFileName)
            Using S As New PdfStamper(R2, FS)
                S.AcroFields.SetField(TextFieldName, "Chris & Mark")
                S.FormFlattening = True
                S.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `writer.addAnnotation(PdfAnnotation);`  PdfFormField derives from PdfAnnotation.  And `TextField`/`RadioCheckField`/`PushbuttonField` are great for creating `PdfFormField` instances Just So.  The various list types use TextField.  This doesn't take up space during layout, but I think you can use a generic tag with a no-stroke-no-fill Rectangle.

Comment: @Mark Storer, I figured you'd have the answer! I didn't inspect the writer itself, I was trying to get a stamper built from it which obviously failed.

Comment: Here is my example file that exhibits the strange "cannot take ampersand" behavior on the particular field of interest.  http://www.removeblankrows.info/testfile.pdf.  Try to put "Chris & Mark" in the field named "form1[0].#subform[0].Table3[0].Row2[0].Line2_FullName_and_AddressofEmployer[0]"  under "Applicant's employment last five years" and flatten the form then view the results.  The ampersand is mysteriously missing for me, but when I just type in the field I can enter it just fine.

Comment: @AudioFrk, I updated my post above, unfortunately (for you) the PDF you send works just fine for me.

Comment: @Chris, I added the code I tested with the the question.  It is a combo of what you provided and the existing code and confirmed that the issue is still occurring.  I am using a different version of iText, 4.1.2.0, but I'm wondering if it's the code I'm using not the version.

Comment: @AudioFrk, I just tried your code 100% exactly as posted with `4.1.6.0` (the only version of 4 that I could find) and it is still displaying the ampersands correctly. Can you post your output PDF somewhere that I can download so I can compare them?

Comment: So strange, I ran the code again and it worked!  This is not making sense, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar case where German umlauts entered by the user in the application were not showing in the PDF. Turned out to be a font issue.
Had to ship our own fonts with the application (Liberation package to get cross-platform Arial-style) and doing this (it's Java):

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(FONT_FILE, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
acroFields.setFieldProperty(fieldName, "textfont", baseFont, null);
```